# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1 on trying to Fetch Array from an Endpoint

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter, I am trying to access **Position** from the json.

```
  {
  "filters": {},
  "competition": {
    "id": 2021,
    "area": {
      "id": 2072,
      "name": "England"
    },
    "name": "Premier League",
    "code": "PL",
    "plan": "TIER_ONE",
    "lastUpdated": "2021-04-17T02:20:14Z"
  },
  "season": {
    "id": 733,
    "startDate": "2021-08-13",
    "endDate": "2022-05-23",
    "currentMatchday": 2,
    "winner": null
  },
  "standings": [
    {
      "stage": "REGULAR_SEASON",
      "type": "TOTAL",
      "group": null,
      "table": [
        {
          "position": 1,
          "team": {
            "id": 563,
            "name": "West Ham United FC",
            "crestUrl": "https://crests.football-data.org/563.svg"
          },
          "playedGames": 2,
          "form": null,
          "won": 2,
          "draw": 0,
          "lost": 0,
          "points": 6,
          "goalsFor": 8,
          "goalsAgainst": 3,
          "goalDifference": 5
        },
        {
          "position": 2,
          "team": {
            "id": 61,
            "name": "Chelsea FC",
            "crestUrl": "https://crests.football-data.org/61.svg"
          },
          "playedGames": 2,
          "form": null,
          "won": 2,
          "draw": 0,
          "lost": 0,
          "points": 6,
          "goalsFor": 5,
          "goalsAgainst": 0,
          "goalDifference": 5
        },
        {
          "position": 3,
          "team": {
            "id": 64,
            "name": "Liverpool FC",
            "crestUrl": "https://crests.football-data.org/64.svg"
          },
          "playedGames": 2,
          "form": null,
          "won": 2,
          "draw": 0,
          "lost": 0,
          "points": 6,
          "goalsFor": 5,
          "goalsAgainst": 0,
          "goalDifference": 5
        },
        {
          "position": 4,
          "team": {
            "id": 397,
            "name": "Brighton & Hove Albion FC",
            "crestUrl": "https://crests.football-data.org/397.svg"
          },
          "playedGames": 2,
          "form": null,
          "won": 2,
          "draw": 0,
          "lost": 0,
          "points": 6,
          "goalsFor": 4,
          "goalsAgainst": 1,
          "goalDifference": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am getting ***RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1*** . when I try to print

> print(${snapshot.data!.standings[0].table.length})

it is giving proper value

Here is my Code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shub4/plmodel.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class FootballLeagues extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FootballLeaguesState createState() => _FootballLeaguesState();
}

class _FootballLeaguesState extends State<FootballLeagues> {
  // var index = 4;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Football Leagues"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<LeagueStandings>(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final data = snapshot.data;
            print("${snapshot.data!.standings[0].table.length}");
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.standings[0].table.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          // Text("hi"),
                          Text(
                              "${data!.standings[index].table[index].position}"),
                          CircleAvatar(
                            child: SvgPicture.network(
                                "${data.standings[index].table[index].team.crestUrl}"),
                          ),
                          Text(
                              "${data.standings[index].table[index].team.name}")
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                });
            // Image.network("${data!.current.condition.icon}");
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If use `Text("Static data")` it is working fine, but only if I get a value from an endpoint it is giving a problem

Answer (score 1):

Replace your item count with the following code

```
itemCount: snapshot.data!.standings!=null?snapshot.data!.standings[0].table.length: 0,
```

You got error because of the list-builder call standings[0] before loading the response from the snapshot.

And also a same mistake in:

```
print(${snapshot.data!.standings[0].table.length})
```

We can go with this as well as

```
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
         List<LeagueStandings> data = <int>[].cast<LeagueStandings>();
         if(snapshot.hasData){
           data = snapshot.data;
            print("${snapshot.data!.standings[0].table.length}");
          }
         return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
```

Comment: still getting the same error after replacing my code with the given

Comment: final List<LeagueStandings> data = List();

     -         List() - is giving an error

Comment: list is deprecated?remove final

Comment: The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled.
Try using a list literal, 'List.filled' or 'List.generate'

Comment: sure you can try both of this. is it solved?

Comment: I used List<LeagueStandings> data = <int>[].cast<LeagueStandings>();

and now I don't see any error but I am seeing only one element, not the entire  list

Comment: write  `item count: data.length` and is it helpful please accept as an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236400/discussion-between-subhist-subedar-and-jahidul-islam).